# How to keep JComponents always centered even after being shrunk?

Tags: java, swing, layout

### Objective

I am making a JPanel with three JComponents on it: a wide custom JComponent, and two custom AbstractButtons which in turn also extends from JComponent.

I'd like to organize my JPanel with 2 rows and 2 columns, with the wide JComponent spanning two columns. There is plenty of space around the AbstractButtons. This is a diagram I drew of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

### Problem

Basically, when the user clicks on one of the AbstractButtons, it shrinks. I'd like them to always be perfectly centered in their cells even when clicked upon. This is not the case in my code when I used GridBagLayout however; the buttons become off-centered and their top-left hand corners stay wherever they were before.

### Code

This is what the code below would display (the red buttons will now shrink after being pressed):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate components needed.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        Button b1 = new Button();
        Button b2 = new Button();
        WideComponent w = new WideComponent();

        // give margins to each component
        EmptyBorder padding = new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20);
        b1.setBorder(padding);
        b2.setBorder(padding);
        w.setBorder(padding);

        // Add stuff to panel
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(w);

        // Add panel to frame, show frame
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}

class Button extends AbstractButton implements MouseListener
{   
    final int WIDTH = 175;
    final int HEIGHT = 75; 
    boolean mousePressed;

    public Button() 
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    // draw method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        if (!mousePressed)
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        else
        {
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH - 30, HEIGHT - 30);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }

    // MouseListener interface implementation
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { mousePressed = true; repaint(); }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) { mousePressed = false; repaint(); }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    // JComponent sizing methods
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }    



}

class WideComponent extends JComponent
{
    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 150; 

    // drawing method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    // JComponent sizing methods
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }    
}
```

Comment: What is the resizing behavior that you want?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'll admit that was probably an exaggeration. It is still answerable without any code, though.

Comment: @Radiodef The buttons simply shrink in width and height when clicked upon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I apologize. I have used your suggestion to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example code doesn't match the picture your drew and it doesn't use a GridBagLayout. A `SSCCE` should replicate the problem with the code you tested.

The problem is the implementation of your custom object. What you really need is a custom property in your class the reflects the current state of your component. Something like:

```
public void setLargeSize(Boolean largeSize)
{
    this.largeSize = largeSize;
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Then you need to modify the getPreferredSize() method to return the size of the component based on this variable:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    if (largeSize)
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    else
        return new Dimension(WIDTH - 30, HEIGHT - 30);
}
```

Now the layout manager can do its job based on the current state of the component.

You would also change your painting code. The painting code doesn't need to check the pressed state because the layout manager has already taken that into consideration. Actually, I dont' think you even need to override paintComponent(). Just set some properties of the button:

```
setBorderPainted( false );
setContentAreaPainted( false );
setFocusPainted( false );
```

You can then set the background color in the setLargeSize(...) method.

Finally the MouseListener would just invoke the `setLargeSize(...)` method with the appropriate parameter.

So now all you need to do is make sure you set up the constraints properly so that the component gets centered in its cell. You may need to set the alignment x/y of your component.

Comment: Your `getPreferredSize()` method should have a return type of `Dimension`, but the answer is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try changing the bounds of the buttons depending on if it's the shrinked size, or the full size? That is only if your main window is not resizable.

Component.setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)